# Error in xml.rpc(.server, method, as.character(blogid), names(login),: Problems

Tags: r, wordpress, knitr

I always get an error when using knit2wp.

```
library(XMLRPC)
library(RWordPress)
library(knitr)

setwd("/Users/you/Documents/FindStox/WP-Posts")

options(WordpressLogin = c(user = '**********'), WordpressURL = 'http://findstox.com/xmlrpc.php')

knit2wp('Post1.Rmd', title = 'Blog Post from R Markdown to WordPress', publish = FALSE)
```

Error in xml.rpc(.server, method, as.character(blogid), names(login),  : 
  Problems

Comment: The recent WordPress update solved the issue.

Comment: Does it still work for you? I'm getting `error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version` now which apparently has to do with XMLRPC.